# Is there a proper name for this kind of toothed disk?

Tags: angle

I'm building a piece of furniture with an adjustable part and would like to use a **toothed disk** similar in concept to the examples show below. Before having it custom made, I am searching for a manufacturer, maybe buy something off-the-shelf. Problem is, I'm not even sure what this would be called... Can you tell me a proper/generic name for this?

A web search for "toothed disk" turns up a lot of cogs and wheels, however only one of those hits is for something similar to what I am looking for (and is discontinued): [image: discontinued Sachtler part]

The concept is that 2 of these disks are fastened to the opposing pieces. Pulling the 2 pieces together with e.g. a bolt causes the teeth to engage, and so the 2 pieces are fastened to each other at a fixed angle, which can be adjusted to suit needs.

Other real life examples that I have seen this used in:

- Height adjustable piano stand: [image: Height adjustable piano stand]
- Adjustable press arm: [image: Adjustable press arm]

Comment: The first picture is called a "Devil's contact lens":. ;)

Comment: Looks like something you could make with a router on a sled, a 45° bit, and a rotary indexing table. I mean, assuming you don't have a little CNC machine :)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

What we have here is a [Hirth Joint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirth_joint).

> A Hirth joint or Hirth coupling is a type of mechanical connection named after its developer Albert Hirth. It is used to connect two pieces of a shaft together and is characterized by tapered teeth that mesh together on the end faces of each half shaft.

Comment: I learn something new here every day. These might help (though I'm not sure about sizes): http://www.nord-lock.com/nord-lock/wedge-locking/washers/introduction/

Comment: Didn't realize that the two halves of the washer weren't separable. Mea culpa.

Comment: Possibly useful for searching, from the WP article: "Hirth-like joints are often found on camera support equipment, where they are called rosettes."

Comment: Thanks @Timbo, that's useful info too. You should consider making it a separate answer just for completeness' sake. I missed that in the WP article...

Comment: I only ever saw not quite those but similar disks in Ikea furniture and there they were used to "dig" into wood to stay in place better.

Comment: @Maurycy: I believe those are generally referred to as 'threaded inserts', 'insert nuts' or 'tee nuts' depending on how they dig into the wood.

Answer (score 11):

Expanding from my comment on isherwood's answer.  From the [Hirth Joint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirth_joint) article:

> Hirth-like joints are often found on camera support equipment, where they are called rosette [joint]s.